# dynamic generation of CSS attributes in CSS files based on user input in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, themes

Most of the dynamic CSS Q & A show how to **swap between** CSS files or predefined CSS values.

My question is: *during a live user session*  **how to compute/compile CSS values for e.g. both** `element.width2` and `width:230px` into the CSS file (`element.width3` and `width:430px;`) before loading it to the client-side browser. *To be clear I am not looking to swap out CSS files via JavaScript, I'm seeking options for a server side answer* **where the CSS file is server generated/recompiled during a session** *is there manipulation class in .Net framework or the razor view engine? or how can I achieve this*

```
// below are static elements, that I want change values and the CSS "keys"
.variable-sizes .element.wdth2 { width: 230px; }
.variable-sizes .element.hght2 { height: 230px; }

.variable-sizes .element.width2.height2 {

  // on the server side, from a usr setting, 
  // can I compute and fill this to some...   Width * UserVal ?  
  font-size: 2.0em;
}
```

Comment: Is this CSS file exclusive to the user or a file that is been shared between all sessions?

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Its shared been all sessions, and has the same name. For e.g its style.css but the values inside change based on the user                               (_computed_ profile- such as access to data sensitivity->color becomes more RED , basic role editor-> color is more green; his rank -  svg icon etc)

Comment: Wouldn't it be worthwhile considering another solution then? It sounds like different users change the same file. Now think of user A changes it and sends a response to a client to load a page (which later triggers the load of the CSS file). In the meanwhile, user B could change the same file therefore user A would get an incorrect style. What sounds more appropriately is to change the style directly on the DOM elements in the client - or any similar solution.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst The file name is the same, think of it as a CSS template - with a CSS values filled-in/change based on the calculated user profile's dynamics sections.  I refrained from separate user specific CSS files because - if I had to have separate CSS files then for every user I would end up with a unique/separate CSS file (nightmare).  I'm exploring other options, and may have found a promising candidate in extending one of the classes in the action namespace

Comment: I understand that. The issue I was mentioning was about having one file for all. Parallel usage is going to be a challenge.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst since the attributes in file are modified on the fly - only for that particular user and his session _it does not need to be persisted_, I believe I can throw away the file while using a common base template. However, its slowed the response down due to the processing of the CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some of it working via [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) just seems a bit old, wondering if its still maintained.